# mongodb connection timeout when callback function after query is slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, timeout

I am working on the back-end of a web application. Server-side, node is used along with express and mongo (via mongoose).

The client can make a post request that does the following:

- load the file location of some data from mongo
- load the file and do some heavy work with it
- send the results to the client

This is done by a function that looks like this:

```
function (req, res, next) {

  // read relevant info from req object, e.g.
  var id = req.body.id;

  mySchema.findById(id, (err, doc) => {

      fs.readFile(doc.location, function (err, data) {

        // do some heavy work with data

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        var bodyContent = [];
        // fill bodyContent

        res.write(JSON.stringify(bodyContent));
        res.end();

      });

  });

};
```

This works fine for small files, but when the files become large and the computations of the "heavy work" take longer to execute, mongo throws connection timeout errors:

```
Error: connection timeout
at Db.<anonymous> (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:169:17)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Db.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Server.listener (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1798:14)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Server.<anonymous> (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:274:14)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Pool.<anonymous> (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:335:12)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (<project path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:185:10)
at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

I have tried to increase the time before timeout as described in other posts related to mongo timeout issues and as described [here](https://gist.github.com/mongolab-org/9959376), but to no avail. What is the best approach to solve such an issue?

---

**Update:**

Looking into the problem more closely, a possible solution seems to be disconnecting Mongo at the start of the callback, e.g. via `mongoose.connection.close()` and re-connect just before the `res.end()` line with something like `mongoose.connect(config)`. However, I have not found a way to do this such that it functions when multiple requests are coming in. Any thoughts on this?